# AWS EB config file, redirect http to https

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I am trying to figure out how to write in the configuration files for deploying an Elastic Beanstalk environment.

I want to do a redirect from http to https.  I can do this through the console after spinning up an application, but I'd like to have it happen automatically.

Something like

```
OptionSettings:
  aws:elbv2:listener:80:
    ListenerEnabled: true
    DefaultProcess: default
    Protocol: HTTP
    Rules: 'httpsonly'
  aws:elbv2:listenerrule:httpsonly:
    # stuff ???
```

I can't seem to find any examples, or the right documentation.

The console rule looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

AWS docs say to do it via server files.

For PHP apache put in `.ebextensions` file

```
files:
   /etc/httpd/conf.d/http-redirect.conf:
     mode: "000644"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content: |
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker
       RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html
and: https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/php/https-redirect-php.config